# HTML not reading my CSS file after firing GULP (4.0)

Tags: html, css, gulp

Shortly put, I've finally managed to make my GULP process to function properly, to be able to simply track and monitor changes in my sass files and HTML files while coding. Everything works, excepted my HMTL is not reading my css file, at all. I made sure that I linked it properly.

I'll put the code below for my gulpfile.js and HTML file

```
const gulp = require('gulp')
const sass = require('gulp-sass')
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create()


gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/public/scss/**/*.scss', { sourcemaps: true })
        .pipe(sass()) //gulp-sass
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/public/css', {sourcemaps: '.'}))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream())
})

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './app/'
        }
    })
    gulp.watch('app/public/scss/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'))
    gulp.watch('app/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload)
    
})

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('watch'))
```

========================

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/public/css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mydiv">
        <h1>Come on dude</h1>
        <p>This isn't working at all</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My file directory for my stuff being:

```
app/
 pages/
 public/
   /css
   /js
   /scss
index.html
```

So yeah, I'm out of ideas. I linked everything properly. I just don't understand.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Without seeing your HTML file, how do we know the path to the CSS is correct?

Comment: I've edited the post and added the HTML code

Comment: Try `href="./app/public/css/style.css"` note the `.` at the beginning.